# How to exclude a shift-tab character from a nested character style?

Tags: adobe-indesign

I have a paragraph that looks like this:

```
NN TitleA TitleB [alt-tab character to push to the right] [an image]
```

Then in the paragraph style I set the first word, which is always a number to characterStyle A. After the first word I set the characterStyle B, which includes the

```
TitleA TitleB [alt-tab character to push to the right] [an image]
```

part. But this is not what I need. I need characterStyle B only for

```
TitleA TitleB
```

and characterStyle C to the

```
[alt-tab character to push to the right] [an image]
```

part.

Comment: So what is the question, exactly? How to do this automatically? How to find it using GREP?

Comment: yes, I don't know how to write a regexp... :s In my need it would be the alt-tab char not included in any charStyle

Comment: @Totty you don't need to code regex 99% of the time, it's got a handy tool where you choose bits of logic from drop down lists.

Comment: p.s. please clarify the alt-tab / shift-tab thing

Comment: I don't know, try to write "aa" then shift-tab and then type "bb". You will see that the "aa" is on the left and "bb" aligned to the right. I've seen this in some lynda tutorials 3 years ago

Comment: Your question says alt-tab, but a comment half way down the page says shift-tab - please clarify, by editing whichever one is wrong. If it should be shift-tab, please edit the question so that it says shift-tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may assign your second Character style to be applied up to 1 Tab Character like this:

[image]

and apply your third Character style as the paragraph default (i.e. set the paragraph formatting equal to the formatting of Character Style C).

Now, to exclude the Shift+Tab character from the process, if your text boxes all have equal widths, you can use a simple Tab character - go to the Tabs panel of the paragraph style, click on the ruler, drag the newly appeared tab arrow to the right of the white area and click the Right-jusified tab button. Now a simple tab character will align your images to the right of the paragraph.

Comment: doesnt work :s with a real tab it works but not with an alt-tab tab..

Comment: how to set the default style

Comment: I think the problem is still with the tab vs alt-tab (still didn't figured out how to apply a default character style, by paragraph style)

Comment: By default character style I mean simply set all the paragraph formatting identical to your Character style C. And what exactly is an Alt+Tab character? As far as I can guess this is a Mac shortcut for "Indent to Here" - if it's really so, then it's selectable in the Nested Styles window as well.

Comment: shift-tab, excuse me!

Comment: Oh, then I would maybe use a regular Tab set with right alignment or, in case you have a variable text box width, use (hello again!) an ENSH character...

Comment: it's not a variable text box.. what should I do then?

Comment: If your text boxes all have equal widths then you can use a simple Tab character - go to the `Tabs` panel of the paragraph style, click on the ruler, drag the newly appeared tab arrow to the right of the white area and click the `Right-jusified tab` button. Now a simple tab character will align your images to the right of the paragraph